# Image overflowing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

I'm writing a wordpress image slider for my wordpress site, the image on the slider keeps overflowing and falling on other content. I've tried the code else where on a plain html file it works fine but it does not work on the wordpress theme. I knwo it's the css but I cannot find the problem. What could I have done wrong? My markup exapmle is here and therefafter my css code for the whole site,

```
  <div style="background-color: gray; height: 300px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">

            <!--Start WOWSlider.com BODY section id = slider-container-->
            <div id = "slider-container">
                <div class = "ws_images"><ul>
                        <li><a href = "http://link addresss1.com"><img src = "http://mysite.loc/files/2012/11/mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x10241.jpg" alt = "Beera-Mu-Klass-Black-500x447" title = "Beera-Mu-Klass-Black-500x447" id = "wows1_0"/></a>Beera mu klass 1</li>
                        <li><a href = "http://link addresss2.com"><img src = "http://mysite.loc/files/2012/11/mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x10241.jpg" title = "Beera-Mu-Klass-White-500x447" id = "wows1_1"/></a>Beera mu klass 2</li>
                        <li><a href = "http://link addresss3.com"><img src = "http://mysite.loc/files/2012/11/mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x10241.jpg" alt = "Celebrating-50-Years-500x447" title = "Celebrating-50-Years-500x447" id = "wows1_2"/></a>Celebrating 50 yrs</li>
                        <li><a href = "http://link addresss4.com"><img src = "http://mysite.loc/files/2012/11/mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x10241.jpg" alt = "mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x1024" title = "mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x1024" id = "wows1_3"/></a>mysite baby!!!</li>
                    </ul></div>
                <div class = "ws_bullets"><div>
                        <a href = "#" title = "Beera-Mu-Klass-Black-500x447">1</a>
                        <a href = "#" title = "Beera-Mu-Klass-White-500x447">2</a>
                        <a href = "#" title = "Celebrating-50-Years-500x447">3</a>
                        <a href = "#" title = "mysite-wall-art-Online29-697x1024">4</a>
                    </div></div>
                <a href = "#" class = "ws_frame"></a>
                <div class = "ws_shadow"></div>
            </div>

            <script src = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/wowslider.js" type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8"></script>
            <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My Css file.

```
        </div>

/* Global */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font-size: 12px; font-family: verdana, arial, georgia; color: #333333; }
#main_container { width: 1015px; margin: 0 auto; }
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p { margin: 10px 0; }
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }
img { border: none; }
a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#333; }

/* Header */
#header { padding: 10px 0 30px; }
#menu_container { padding-bottom: 25px; }
#menu_container ul { list-style-type: none; margin-right: 25px; float: left; }
#menu_container ul li { float: left; }
#menu_container ul li a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; background-color: #000; padding: 6px 5px; margin-right: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; display: block; }
#menu_container ul li a:hover { background-color: #858585; }
#menu_container ul li.current-menu-item a, #menu_container ul li.current_page_item a { background-color: #858585; }
#menu_container input[type=text] { width: 172px; height: 25px; background-color: #000; color: #fff; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; float: right; border: none; padding: 0 5px; }

.header_social_icons_cont { float: right; margin-right: 5px; }
.header_social_icons_cont img { float: left; margin-right: 7px; }

/* Content */
.home_post_cont { float: left; margin-right: 34px; width: 228px; min-height: 331px; margin-bottom: 35px; position: relative; }
.home_post_cont_last { margin-right: 0; }
.home_post_cont img { width: 228px; height: 331px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.home_post_cont h3 { font-size: 14px; }
.home_post_cont h3 a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
.home_post_cont h3 a:hover {  text-decoration: none; color: #666; }

.home_post_content { color: #A0A0A0; font-size: 12px; padding-right: 30px; font-weight: normal; height: 270px; }
.home_post_content .in_title { color: #fff; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; font-weight: bold; }
.home_post_content h4 a { color: #fff; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; }
/*.home_post_cat { position: absolute; bottom: -20px; left: 10px; color: #A0A0A0; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 40px; }*/
.home_post_cat { color: #A0A0A0; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 40px; }
.home_post_cat a { color: #A0A0A0 !important; text-decoration: none; }
.home_post_cat a:hover {  text-decoration: none; color: #666; }

.single_left { float: left; width: 665px; }
.single_left h1 { font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0; }

    .hover_caption {
      /* If you can count of CSS3 support: */
      background-color: /*rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)*/ #000; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;

      /* Or use a transparent image if you need to support bad browsers: */
      /*background-image: url(images/hover_caption_bg.png);*/

      /* NOTE: If you're img elements have paddings or margins you'll need to
      match them here to get things lined up properly. */
    }

#commentform input[type=submit] { background-color: #000; border: none; color: #fff; padding: 8px 10px; }
#commentform a { color: #000; }

.commentlist a { color: #000; }    
.iphone-home-image { width: 300px !important; }

/* Sidebar */
#sidebar { float: right; width: 270px; }
.side_box { margin-bottom: 25px; }
.side_box h3 { padding: 5px 5px; background-color: #000; margin-top: 0; color: #fff; }
.side_box p { padding: 0px 5px; }
.side_box ul { list-style-type: none; margin-left: 5px; }
.side_box ul li { margin-bottom: 3px; }
.textwidget { padding: 5px; }

/* Footer */
#footer { margin: 25px 0; padding: 12px 0; border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCB; border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB; color: #8C8889; text-align: right; }
#footer a { color: #8C8889; text-decoration: none; }
#footer a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }


#infscr-loading { text-align: center; }


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#main_container { width: 320px; }
#menu_container { display: none; }
.home_post_cont { margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; float: none; clear: both; }
#footer { display: none; }
#commentform textarea { width: 220px; }
#sidebar { display: none; }
.single_left { float: none; width: 228px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.single_left img { width: 228px; height:inherit; }

}

#slider-container { 
    zoom: 1;
position: relative;
max-width: 920px;
max-height: 300px;
z-index: 100;
border: none;
text-align: left;
}
* html #slider-container{ width:920px }
#slider-container .ws_images ul{
    position:relative;
    width: 10000%; 
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    overflow: visible;
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
#slider-container .ws_images ul li{
    width:1%;
    line-height:0; /*opera*/
    float:left;
    font-size:0;
    padding:0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin:0 0 0 0 !important;
}

#slider-container .ws_images{
    position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
#slider-container .ws_images a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    color:transparent;
}
#slider-container img{
    max-width: none !important;
}
#slider-container .ws_images img{
    width:100%;
    border:none 0;
    max-width: none;
}
#slider-container a{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    outline: none; 
    border: none; 
}

#slider-container  .ws_bullets { 
    font-size: 0px; 
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:70;
}
#slider-container  .ws_bullets div{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#slider-container  a.wsl{
    display:none;
}

#slider-container .ws_bullets { 
    padding: 10px; 
}
#slider-container .ws_bullets a { 
    margin-left: 5px; 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; 
    color: transparent; 
    text-indent: 0px; 
    background-image:url("data:image/gif;base64,");
    position:relative;
}
#slider-container .ws_selbull { 
    background-color: #B8C4CF; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}

#slider-container .ws_bullets a:hover, #slider-container .ws_overbull { 
    background-color: #dae9f6;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}

#slider-container a.ws_next, #slider-container a.ws_prev {
    font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-15px;
    line-height:30px;
    z-index:60;
    background-color: #000000; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    padding: 0px 10px; 
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
}
#slider-container a.ws_next{
    right:0;
}
#slider-container a.ws_prev {
    left:0;
}
* html #slider-container a.ws_next,* html #slider-container a.ws_prev{display:block}
#slider-container:hover a.ws_next, #slider-container:hover a.ws_prev {display:block}
/* bottom center */
#slider-container  .ws_bullets {
    top:0;
    right: 0;
}

#slider-container .ws-title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right:5px;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px 1%;
    width:98%;
    font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity:0.55;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=55); 
}
#slider-container .ws-title div{
    padding-top:5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#slider-container .ws_images ul{
    animation: wsBasic 16.8s infinite;
    -moz-animation: wsBasic 16.8s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: wsBasic 16.8s infinite;
}
@keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 12.5%{left:-0%} 25%{left:-100%} 37.5%{left:-100%} 50%{left:-200%} 62.5%{left:-200%} 75%{left:-300%} 87.5%{left:-300%} }
@-moz-keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 12.5%{left:-0%} 25%{left:-100%} 37.5%{left:-100%} 50%{left:-200%} 62.5%{left:-200%} 75%{left:-300%} 87.5%{left:-300%} }
@-webkit-keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 12.5%{left:-0%} 25%{left:-100%} 37.5%{left:-100%} 50%{left:-200%} 62.5%{left:-200%} 75%{left:-300%} 87.5%{left:-300%} }

#slider-container .ws_bullets  a img{
    text-indent:0;
    display:block;
    top:12px;
    left:-79px;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    border: 2px solid #B8C4CF;
    max-width:none;
}
#slider-container .ws_bullets a:hover img{
    visibility:visible;
}

#slider-container .ws_bulframe div div{
    height:48px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
#slider-container .ws_bulframe div {
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#B8C4CF;
    width:157px;
}
#slider-container  .ws_bullets .ws_bulframe{
    display:none;
    top:25px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 2px solid #B8C4CF;
}
#slider-container .ws_bulframe span{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: We can't find it either. Show a markup example of the problem. (Please don't paste a complete Wordpress page here.)

Comment: You've posted much more code here than I care to look at.  A smaller, self contained example will get you better answers.

Comment: Those lines sounds problematic : `#slider-container .ws_images ul { width: 10000%;} #slider-container .ws_images ul li { width: 1%;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `overflow:hidden` in some div.